# Material-UI: unsupported non-unitless line height with grid alignment. Use unitless line heights instead

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In many ReactJs projects one of them is throwing below error:

```
Error: Material-UI: unsupported non-unitless line height with grid
alignment. Use unitless line heights instead.
```

while defining lineHeight in `px`, below is my code:

```
const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({});

let theme = createMuiTheme({
     typography: {
        allVariants: {
            fontFamily
        },
        h1: {
            fontWeight: 600,
            fontSize: 26,
            lineHeight: '32px',
            [breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
                fontSize: 18,
                lineHeight: '26px',
            }
        },
        h2: {
            fontWeight: 600,
            fontSize: 20,
            lineHeight: 28 / 20
        },
        h3: {
            fontWeight: 600,
            fontSize: 16,
            lineHeight: '22px',
            [breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
                fontSize: 14,
                lineHeight: '20px',
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In the above example, if I change `lineHeight` of `h1` or `h2` to `px` value, it throws an error, but does not throw an error for `h3` rather I define lineHeight in `px` or unitless value.

above code throwing an error because I defined lineHeight of `h1` in `px` and I starts working if I change it to below code:

```
h1: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    fontSize: 26,
    lineHeight: 32 / 26
},
```

suggest me why this is happening. I searched but didn't find any related issues on StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you using `responsiveFontSizes` somewhere?

Comment: @RyanCogswell, yes I'm using media query in typography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, somewhere in your code you are using the [responsiveFontSizes function](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) since it contains the [code that throws this error](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/styles/responsiveFontSizes.js#L48).

The error isn't occurring for your `h3` because of the following [condition within responsiveFontSizes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/styles/responsiveFontSizes.js#L38):

```
    if (remFontSize <= 1) {
      return;
    }
```

Your `h3` has a font-size of 16 which is 1 rem, so `responsiveFontSizes` doesn't do anything for that variant and therefore doesn't throw the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I have not added this condition in my project, maybe Material-UI is doing this.

Comment: I provided the link to the exact location in the Material-UI code where this condition is from. It is in the `responsiveFontSizes` function.

Comment: Ohhh, awesome, but why material is adding this condition?

Comment: `responsiveFontSizes` uses the initial font size in the theme as the max font size and then calculates a min size from that. I think it wants to avoid making anything that starts out `<= 1 rem` any smaller.

Comment: Fantastic!!! In the end for me, it was my line-heights that were set with rem values!! Thank you @RyanCogswell How do you know so much about MUI :)